# Spring Boot Actuator to show service start datetime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring-boot-starter-actuator in my project wanted to show service starts date time along with other information on **/info** end point.
Please guide how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/startup` - is the Actuator Endpoint to see the startup information.

Sample URL syntax:

```
http://<HOST>:<port>/actuator/startup
```

For more info, visit [here](https://medium.com/techwasti/startup-actuator-endpoint-spring-boot-54a8dd0a1fdb.)

--- Edit---

1. `/startup` endpoint does not get exposed by default, Hence need to enable explicitly by below property in application.properties :

   management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=startup
2. `BufferingApplicationStartup` class is in-memory buffered implementation for capturing startup steps. Hence in the main class below changes are required:

   import java.util.TimeZone;

   import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.context.metrics.buffering.BufferingApplicationStartup;

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class ActuatorEndpointApplication {

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // SpringApplication.run(ActuatorEndpointApplication.class, args);

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ActuatorEndpointApplication.class);
        app.setApplicationStartup(new BufferingApplicationStartup(2048));
        app.run(args);

    }
   ```

   }
3. Now test the url:

   `http://<HOST>:<port>/actuator/startup` in Chrome/Postman.

For more info, refer [here](https://springhow.com/spring-boot-startup-actuator-endpoint/)

Comment: For me it is not showing /startup endpoint in http://<HOST>:<port>/actuator. Also showing 404 when http://<HOST>:<port>/actuator/startup

Comment: @NaliniWanjale Uploaded a sample spring boot project in github for reference- https://github.com/arunsai271/Spring_Boot_Actuator_Endpoint_Examples